# Программа выдаёт ошибку при создании автономного файла

Tags: java, javafx, gui

Я создал приложение с использованием javafx
В Intelij IDEA выполняю создание автономного файла по следующей инструкции:

```
Cоздайте артефакт:
```

File -> Project Structure -> Project Settinfs -> Artifacts -> + ->javaFX Application -> From module 'Your Module Name'

Справа во вкладке JavaFX задайте:
Application Class: ваш класс с точкой входа - методом main
Native Bondle: All

Проверьте, что Output directory задана правильно (по умолчанию в папку out\artifacts вашего проекта)

```
Сбилдите артефакт:
```

Build -> Build Artifacts -> 'Ваш артифакт' -> Build
 И как раз после выполнения этого действия вылетает ошибка:
[image: ошибка]

Текст первой ошибки:

```
Error:Java FX Packager: 
BUILD FAILED
Error reading project file C:\Users\OurWo\.IdeaIC2018.2\system\compile-server\курсовая_с_графическим_интерфейсом_b08f2e59\_temp_\build.xml: Invalid byte 2 of 3-byte UTF-8 sequence.
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Текст второй ошибки:
`Error:Java FX Packager: fx:deploy task has failed`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что с этим делать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не используй русские буквы в названии проекта